# Excel Oledb Update Query - Updating header row in Excel 2016

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, insert-update, oledbcommand

Trying to update the rows in Excel using Oledb, but update query updates Header row in Excel 2016.

**It works perfectly fine in Excel 2010** or earlier, just wondering what is required in Excel 2016? To have this worked.

Excel sheet is as below,

[image]

The connection string used for Connect is as below,

> `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"";`

Update query used as below,

```
Update [Sheet1$A2:C] set [Head 1] = 'ABC'  Where [Rno]=1
```

The output of this query in Excel 2016.

[image]

Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No it's not working when I remove A2:C as the header is at A2, 
Where clause in update is required because I need to update record by Rno

Comment: Change your connection string to version 16.0 instead of 12.0.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Office

Comment: I created a test Excel file that looks exactly like the posted worksheet. I Used the “exact” code you have posted for the OleDb connection string in addition to the using the same query… and the code appears to work as expected. The current code does not reproduce the issue you describe. There must be something else going on. I am using Office 2019.

Comment: @JohnG - How do I demonstrate the issue exists? it is working with old version but for 2016 it is updating the header, something must be wrong but what is that I need help with it.

Comment: Well, I have tried numerous ways to re-create what you describe. The connection string looks odd and can be cleaned up, however, in cases where the connection string had problems, an error is thrown. It is a little confusing when you say it does not work for 2016… I tested the code using both `xls` and `xlsx` files and both worked as expected. I would think using both `xls` and `xlsx` files would apply to all versions of Excel. How do you know the file was saved specifically from an Excel 2016 version?

Comment: In other words, what do you mean by it does not work with “version 2016”? Does this mean the code works with other (non-2016 version) `xlsx` files? Or does it fail with ALL `xlsx` files? I would think that if the code worked with at least one or more files with an `xlsx` extension (which is the Excel 2016 extension), and, this ONE file fails… then… I would look at that specific file. Can you clarify if this happens to ALL `xlsx` files or just this one?

Comment: @JohnG - Thanks John for spending time, 
Update query working in all the cases with 2010 or 2013, xlsx files or xls or xlsm files, 

but challenge I am facing is, in 2016 version it is updating the column header, 
if you look at my query, I am updating with Rno but still, it is going and updating the header.

I guess there is no video attach support in stack overflow, otherwise, I would have shown you.

Comment: A video is not necessary, I have no reason to doubt that what you say is happening is actually happening, even if I cannot reproduce the issue. It seems odd that ONLY 2016 files would fail. Are these 2016 files coming from one particular machine? Have you reset the 2016 Excel preferences and created a new file? I feel you may be off base in relation to the problem being specific to the 2016 version. I would look closer at the file and any particular software/computer that created the file. It may be one particular machine with an out of whack Excel  2016.

Comment: I am just saying that your focus and blanket statement… _”saying, the problem is related to Excel Version 2016”_ … may well be true, however I feel the jury is still out on that and further research is needed before convicting the 2016 version.